# Saving a Datatable created at runtime to an empty mdb

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, datatable

Hello I have a Datatable and with 36 columns and about 112000 records and an empty mdb file, what is the best way to add that table to the empty mdb database?

do i have to use the SQL Command `CREATE TABLE` and add each column manually to the created Datatable then use the SQL `insert` command?

is there something like `SqlBulkCopy` that can be used for this task?
note the Datatable is created at runtime and never been in a database most of the data is taken from XML files

Comment: Isn't it mostly answered here ?
http://stackoverflow.com/q/2025501/78522

Comment: This is what i am doing already, read the comment in the answer below for more info

Comment: The link iDevlop showed you is the short simple way.

Comment: What do you do to the XML files that the datatable is based on ? Do you just add them successively or do you perform complex operations?

Comment: i add 31 columns to the data table and i only get 5 coulmns from the xml files, and yes alot of calculations are performed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the best way is to use `OleDBAdapter` class. You need to first build your database before you proceed this process. As it is needed by the `OleDBAdapter`. If you recall, you use the DataAdapter's `Fill()` method to read the contents of a table in a database and fill our locally-cached DataTable object.

There are 3 steps to saving data in ADO.Net:

- Get a locally cached copy of the data with the `Fill()` method
- Write code (or use a control) that makes changes to the locally cached copy
- Save the changes back to the underlying database with the `Update()` method

Here's the code,

```
Using conn As New OleDBConnection("connectionString Here")
    Using comm As New OleDBCommand()
        With comm
            .Connection = conn
            .CommandType = CommandType.CommandText
            .CommandText = "SELECT * FROM youTableName"
        End With
        Using adapter As New OleDBDataAdapter(comm)
            Dim _dataTable As New DataTable()
            adapter.Fill(_dataTable)

            'add you records here  '
            ' preferably by using loop '
            Dim _dataRow As DataRow
            _dataRow = _dataTable.NewRow()
            _dataRow("colNameA") = "valueA"
            _dataRow("colNameB") = "valueB"
            '........ '
            _dataTable.Rows.Add(_dataRow)

            Dim dt_changes As DataTable
            dt_changes = _dataTable.Changes()
            If Not IsNothing(dt_changes) Then
                Using commBuild As OleDbCommandBuilder(adapter)
                    Dim rowCount as Integer = adapter.Update(dt_changes)
                    MsgBox(rowCount  & " updated")
                End Using
            End If
        End Using
    End Using
End Using
```